# DIY Repair but want to know if I have the correct part

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I am wanting to make sure I have the correct SMD piece to fix this laptop. A while back had a laptop that burnt out, wanted to repair it myself instead of paying the company to repair it instead because its not under warranty. So found the piece that burnt out and wanted to make sure before I start repair what chip I need because I ordered one from Mouser but I have a feeling its the wrong one, and to avoid screwing up and making it just more broken, I need to know what the chip is and is the one I ordered to replace it, the correct one.

So the chip that I believe I need to get is this one  [image] which is a R82826070 (R82-826-070).

This is what I bought from [Mouser](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Coiltronics-Eaton/HCM1A0703-R82-R?qs=%2Fha2pyFaduiVFnuVTsyfsO%252Bh8hD3WAjtbUW%2FjONoMK3iNCwDTCkQiA%3D%3D). Is this the correct SMD or did I goof up?

Comment: Are you going to replace the part that reads R82, or the part above it that is charred beyond recognition?

Comment: Charred one, it seems to be the correct one.

Comment: These don't burn easily; if they do then there was likely some high current going through a voltage regulator nearby. In which case that regulator and likely any diode(s) in the same circuit are toast too. And the overcurrent could have been caused by another fault elsewhere. So... not the easiest thing to repair.

Answer (score 2):

Repair tech here. This is an inductor for some high-power circuit (CPU/GPU or something else that requires high current; given the replacement spec, probably not CPU/GPU, but still something relatively current-hungry). You seem to have chosen the part correctly (impossible to be certain; I would advice to pick a coil with small resistance but maximum acceptable DC current spec within financial reason), but the inductors don't usually go bad on their own, this usually happens if there is a short circuit on the line they're installed on, and because of short circuit the current through the inductor exceeds its maximum DC current spec, causing it to burn.

Of course, I don't know what exactly happened to the device, I'm just pointing out that the coil usually doesn't die alone. You're welcome to replace it, but be mentally ready to either have another coil burn or the device not start (if short circuit protection on that power line kicks in quickly enough before the coil burns).

Of course, telepathic diagnostic is not my strong suit. Hope for the best, but be ready for the worst in this case.

Also, I don't really know how you're going to replace it without some kind of equipment. It's doable with soldering station (clumsy, awkward, painful, but doable), and I doubt you have hot air station (but congrats if you do)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like the part (0.82uH inductor.) This would be for a fairly high-current dc-dc converter that switches at a high frequency.

But… what caused it to fry? That’s the next thing to check into.

Comment: Okay, so I got the right part, that is good. The part that caused it well.. lets just say a learning lesson that should of been a bit more clear (sustain load on a laptop for testing), was pushing it for way too long tbh).